# How can I solve a non-homogenous exact equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Above we have the problem in question. It is a non-exact, non-homogeneous question. I already solved the general solution by finding and integrating factor, etc.

The answer to the general homogeneous is sec(x)y + c.

However, I run into trouble finding the particular solutions.

I know for higher order differential equations such as y'' + y'+3y = something.

I can use methods such as undetermined coefficients, variation of parameters, even operational methods! But I have never seen this case.

Please help.

Comment: **Hint:** Did you consider Integrating Factor? Divide by $\cos x$ and then look at the form. After, you end up with expressions that can be integrated on the LHS and RHS.

Comment: @Moo, thank you so much. I am in shock. I never expected to be dealing with a separable diff. E.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos (x) y'+ \sin (x) y=2 \cos ^3 x \sin x$$
$$\dfrac {\cos (x) y'+ \sin(x) y}{\cos ^2 x}=2 \cos  x \sin x$$
$$\left (\dfrac {y}{\cos (x)} \right )'= \sin (2x)$$
Integrate both sides.

---

You can also change the variable
$$\cos (x) y'+ \sin (x) y=2 \cos ^3 x \sin x$$
$$\cos (x) \dfrac {dy}{d \cos x} \frac {d \cos x}{dx}+ \sin (x) y=2 \cos ^3 x \sin x$$
$$-\sin x \cos (x) \dfrac {dy}{d \cos x} + \sin (x) y=2 \cos ^3 x \sin x$$
$$- \cos (x) \dfrac {dy}{d \cos x} + y=2 \cos ^3 x$$
$$- u \dfrac {dy}{d u} + y=2 u^3$$
Where $u= \cos x$